# How to implement URL Rewriting in ASP.Net?

Tags: c#, asp.net

In my project i want to implement url rewrite . At present my urls like http://example.com/?user=someone&time=20min. I want to make it like http://example.com/someone/20mins/

I tried the examples mentioned here

**www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/akkiraju/url-rewriting-in-Asp-Net/**

But getting issue , like PAGE NOT FOUND error.

I followed same instructions and hosted my application in IIS as well.

Thanks,
venky.

Comment: You can also use the IIS UrlRewrite module to do this.

Answer (score 0):

In the web page you mentioned the code is like this :
 [image: Code]

I presume the problem being the absolute url starting with "/". Replace it with tilde and slash  "~/" and see if it works :

eg. : 
instead of : translationPath="/MyPage?Param1=x&Param2=y" 
use : "~/MyPage?Param1=x&Param2=y"

I'm guessing that you have hosted your app on a virtual directory in IIS. That's why it cannot find the address.

Comment: My code is like this......`code`
                switch (requestPath.ToLower())
                {

                    case "/laptops/dell/":                   
                        translationPath = "~/showitem.aspx?itemid=5";
                        break;

                    case "/laptops/hp/":
                        translationPath = "~/showitem.aspx?itemid=6";
                        break;
                    default:
                        translationPath = "~/default.aspx";
                        break;
                }